# A transformation problem in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

any idea how to approach this?

given:
$$
T:R^3\rightarrow R^3
$$
$$
T(a,b,c)=(b,c,a)
$$
$$
B={(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,1)}
$$
find $[3T^{n+2}+3T^{n+1}+3T^n]_B$ for every n

Comment: Have you tried applying the transformation with n=1 or n=2 and looked for a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to check that, for $\forall x\in R^3$,
$$ Tx=\left(\begin{matrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0
\end{matrix}\right)x. $$
So
$$ T^{3k}=I,(T^2+T+I)x=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&1&1\\
1&1&1\\
1&1&1
\end{matrix}\right)x. $$
For $n=3k$, $T^{3n}=I$ and hence
$$ (3T^{n+2}+3T^{n+1}+3T^n)B=3T^n(T^2+T+I)B=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&1&1\\
1&1&1\\
1&1&1
\end{matrix}\right)B. $$
You can do the rest for $n=3k+1,n=3k+2$.